# PhpStorm custom Language Injection

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have PHP array elements like this:

```
[
    'thisIsJs' => "alert('Hello world');",
]
```

In PhpStorm, I'd like to have the values be automatically recognised as containing JavaScript (e.g. syntax highlighting).

It looks like creating a new/custom "Language Injection" is what I'd want, but there's almost no documentation on them, because they're not intended to be changed by users.

I think it'd be something like the existing `"SQL select/delete/insert/update/create"`, only checking an array value and doing a `/Js$/` regex on the array key.

Is this possible?

Comment: I very doubt that it's possible to achieve for array values (I mean -- inject some language if array key has a special name). But if you write a custom plugin then it's more likely to be achievable.

Comment: The `"SQL select/delete/insert/update/create"` is based on string content so injection takes place in either existing string (where the needed text is already present) or after you type enough text so it gets triggered. But yes, you may create an Injection rule that will inject JavaScript into ALL strings where `alert()` will be found. P.S. Please note that the syntax used is not RegEx but reg-ex alike.

Comment: At the same time, you can try injecting a language via PHPDoc like comment -- it needs to be placed just before the sting, e.g. `'thisIsJs' => /** @lang JavaScript */ "alert('Hello world');"` -- syntax colors do not appear but completion seems to be working. You can also use Alt+Enter quick fix menu (the light bulb one) and inject that way (although in this case it shoudl be a temp injection...)

Comment: Thanks, `/** @lang JavaScript */` is what I'd thought of first, but then thought it'd be better if it could happen automatically based on the key name.

Comment: @LazyOne I do get syntax highlighting with PHPDoc comments (though I've just upgraded to 2019.2, perhaps it's new in this version).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yeah, must be. I don't have it in 2019.1.3 but it's there in 2019.2